# Umar ibn al-Khattab: Hold onto your salat

Tags: source-identification

> *Hold on to your salah, because if you lose that, you will lose
>   everything else.* **—Umar ibn al-Khattab** (May Allah be pleased with him.)

What is a reliable source I can cite to record this quote?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a statement of 'Umar ibn al-Khattab?, I found a close statement of 'Umar ibn 'Abdal'aziz saying: اجتنبوا الاشتغال عند حضرة الصلاة، فمن أضاعها فهو لما سواها من شعائر الإسلام أشد تضييعا avoid being busy at the time of prayer, as the one who missed/lost it, will be losing other indications of Islam in a worse manner. 'Umar ibn al-Khattab said something similar: إذا رأيتم الرجل يضيع من الصلاة، فهو لغيرها من حق الله أشد تضييعاً. if you saw a person careless about the prayer, then this person would be less thorough for the other rights of Allah.

Comment: @Medi1Saif♦ Right at the beginning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5LUbYoP0lY